# Finding Asymptotic Lower and Upper Bounds for Recurrence Equations with Root Numbers

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

The sources I have been using makes it confusing for me to grasp a generalized method for the recurrence equations with root numbers.

For instance,

$T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + \sqrt{n} $

One can write this equation in this form;

$T(n) = 2^kT(\frac{n}{2^{2k}}) + 2^{k-1}\sqrt{n} $

I cannot decide which values should I assign for the calculation of the asymptotic bounds. Frankly, I cannot continue confidently.

To elaborate my question another example might be;

$T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n}) + n$

How should one treat the $n$'s ($n$ and $\sqrt{n}$) out of the recurrence equation $T(...)$ for the complexity analysis?

Comment: BTW - your first recurrence in terms of $k$ is incorrect (in particular, it should not be $2^{k-1}\sqrt{n}$ but $2(1-2^{-(k-1)})\sqrt{n}$). Anyhow, presumably you're looking to get a result of the type $T = O(f(n))$. For this, note that you're implicitly given that there are fixed constants $c,C$ s.t. $n \le c \implies T(n) \le C.$ Now, how many iterations ($k$, as a function of $n$) do you need before $n /4^k < c$? What happens when you plug that value of $k$ into the recurrence?

Comment: For your second question, let $S(n) := T(n)/n$. You have $S(n) = S(\sqrt{n}) + \sqrt{n}.$ Now again, how many square roots can you take until you get below $c$?